# Ignore pattern in split()

Tags: java, regex, split

I want to Split a String delimited by '|'. But want to ignore a String value that has '|'.
Find below example:

```
String s = "Shashank|Sam|Location|20246|India|City in India|USA Country|Location|India Specific 2021|25236|A";
```

I want to consider `Location|India Specific 2021` as one value.

Expected Output:

```
Shashank
Sam
Location
20246
India
City in India
USA Country
Location|India Specific 2021
25236
A
```

Whenever I find `Location|India` in String, I want to ignore `|` in that.

I tried using

```
(?<!Location|India)\|
```

But output is

```
Shashank
Sam
Location|20246
India
City in India
USA Country
Location|India Specific 2021
25236
A
```

Thanks

Comment: But in this case if I have only Location as a value , it will consider that.
Like Shashank|Sam|Location|25643|Location|India.
In this I will get Location|25643 also

Comment: Why was the pipe constructed between `Location` and other text ? To assign the status as a non-delimiter is a conceptual error . The source should be `"Shashank|Sam|Location 20246|India|City in India|USA Country|Location India Specific 2021|25236|A"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this regex with a negative lookahead with a nested lookbehind:

```sh
\|(?!(?<=Location\|)India )
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qlVAT8/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\|`: Match a `|`
- `(?!`: Start negative lookahead

  - `(?<=Location\|)`: Make sure that we have `Location|` before current position
  - `India` : Match `India`
- `)`: End negative lookahead

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<!\bLocation)\||\|(?!India\b)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/r5ukrM/1)

This regular expression matches a pipe character (`\|`) that is not preceded by `'Location'` or (`|`) a pipe character that is not followed by `'India'`. `(?<!\bLocation)` is a *negative lookbehind*; `(?!India\b)` is a *negative lookahead*.

The word boundary (`\b`) following `'India'` is to permit a match of `'|'` in (for example) `'Location|Indiana'` (similar for the word boundary before `'Location'`).